# How can I check if a specific char exists in a char array

Tags: c

How can I search for a specific character in a char array ?

Follow my code, but I think it's not correct in the function `strchr`:

```
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
   for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      c2[i] = c;
      int test = strchr(";", c2[i]);
   }
   printf("%c", c);
}
```

I have a structure that has int index, int data, and a pointer to the next register. I fill an array (c2[100]) with some data that come from my .cvs file. In the first register of my array I got something like this: 800;lucas    . I need to find the character ';' in this array and split it, and then the number 800 will be the structure->index and the name 'lucas' will be the structure->data.

Comment: man 3 strchr - do this on a shell and read the man page to understand what `strchr` does.

Comment: How did you declare `c` and `c2`?

Comment: I really don't have a clue what this code is doing. What is the character you are trying to find? Is it `c2[i]`? Is it intentional that your loop ends at 0? (`i < 1` means your `i` is never `> 0`)

Comment: Why do you need loop, if it has only one iteration?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You do realize that your loop runs only once?

Comment: they are declared like... char c; char c2[100];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each character that is read, you are storing it into the first slot of your `c2[]` array (ignoring the rest of the array), and then calling `strchr()` to check if the read character is a `;` or not.  Using `strchr()` for that is overkill.  The following would be much simplier:

```
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{ 
    if (c == ';')
    {
        ...
    }
    printf("%c", c); 
}
```

If you are actually trying to search your array instead, then you are using `strchr()` the wrong way.  It should be more like this instead, assuming `c2[]` already contains the null-terminated string data you want to search in:

```
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{ 
    int test = strchr(c2, c); 
    ...
    printf("%c", c); 
}
```

Comment: I have a structure that has int index, int data, and a pointer to the next register. I fill an array (c2[100]) with some data that come from my .cvs file. In the first register of my array I got something like this: 800;lucas    . I need to find the character ';' in this array and split it, and then the number 800 will be the structure->index and the name 'lucas' will be the structure->data.

Comment: Then use the second example I gave you, where the first parameter of `strchr()` is passed your buffer that contains the `"800;lucus"` string. However, you mention that you want to split the buffer, in which case you can use `strtok()`, or better `sscanf()`, instead of using `strchr()`.